# How to get same face area perimeter in a quad area

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh divided up, and on different parts of the mesh depending on the topology, the face area
has a different perimeter value. Is there a way I can copy/paste the value of one particular area on another quad section? I tried moving the vertices around making them bigger smaller, and its a tedious process.

[image]

Comment: What benefit are you looking to get out of having the faces all the same size?  I don't know an easy way to achieve it, but maybe if you tell us the end goal we might be able to make a useful suggestion that way instead?

Comment: I believe the Mesh Tools addon let's you specify a face area... Not sure how useful it is though :).

Comment: For example, if I need to make certain areas on the mesh to have the same circular depth within the mesh, as seen in the example. But because the area is not the same, each circle has a different  depth radius, if there was a way to get the same mesh perimetre, all the circular depths would looks the same:  https://ibb.co/CmC9Xc0

Comment: LoopTools >  Circle,  and  Cast, both have radius settings, or even ctrl-shift-B bevel a central vertex ... If  the circles are smaller than the face, you can make them the same size, even if the faces are not.